# In the flag summary, put the pending flags on top of old ones for flags on the same post

Tags: feature-request, flags, comment-flags, flag-history

When viewing your flag summary, you are presented with a list of flags, sorted by post. If you flag a bunch of comments on the same post, those are all listed together... including pending flags on those posts. Those pending flags raised later than the handled flags, will then show under the handled flags on that post:

[image]

...or, for a slightly more extreme example:

[image]

When scrolling through the flag summary page, it'd be more useful to see which ones are pending on top of the handled ones. When they're buried under the handled ones, it's easier to miss.

Comment: You can hide all flags except pending flags using the right sidebar.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog - yes, but that lacks context (such as if this is a repeat flag), which is something I'm often looking for. Granted, I use that page a lot more and for different reasons than most people, but...